# Magento - Adding New Column to Sales Order Grid Not Working

Tags: magento, grid, admin, ecommerce-sales

I'm trying to add a new column to Magento's sales order grid (Admin > Sales > Orders). I tried following the instructions located here:
http://www.atwix.com/magento/customize-orders-grid/

I have copied the core file to the local folder so I can override it:

From: /public_html/wholesale/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php

To: /public_html/wholesale/app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php

What's curious is that no matter what changes I make to EITHER file, nothing changes on the admin side. I can't even get a Mage::log() to work.

Once I get past that problem, I need to make sure that the changes I'm making are the right ones. I'm only trying to get the customer's company name. Here are the two pieces I've added:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    // This line is from the original
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());

    // This is the call where I try to bring in the extra field
    // from another sales table
    $collection->getSelect()->join(
        'sales_flat_order_address',
        'sales_flat_order.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id',
        array('company')
    );

    // These lines are also default
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

In _prepareColumns():

```
$this->addColumn('company', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Company'),
    'index' => 'billing_company',
));
```

FYI, I'm using Magento 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    // This line is from the original
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());

    // Join billing 'company' field from sales_flat_order_address table 
    $collection->getSelect()->join(
        array('addressTable' => 'sales_flat_order_address'),
        'main_table.entity_id = addressTable.parent_id AND addressTable.address_type = "billing"',
        array('billing_company'=>'company')
    );

    // These lines are also default
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function filterBillingCompany($collection, $column) {
    $val = (string)trim($column->getFilter()->getValue());
    if ($val != "") {
        $collection->getSelect()->where("addressTable.company LIKE '%{$val}%'");
    }
    return $this;
}
```

In _prepareColumns():

```
$this->addColumn('company', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Company'),
    'index' => 'billing_company',
    'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, 'filterBillingCompany'),
));
```